# How to configure and access IIS in windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7, asp.net

I've installed IIS on Windows 7(Ultimate) by going to control panel>add/remove features/ then checking the IIS.
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/APSNET.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/APSNET.png)
How do I access something like a preference editor like in wamp server.
In wamp server I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin. And accessing the pages I made in http://localhost/pages/
What about in IIS? How do I access something like phpmyadmin. And how do I access the webpages that I made. 
This is only for educational purposes. And I do not need a site to be accessible on the net.

And I already have something like this:[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/IIS.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/IIS.png)

And I see this whenever I try to access a page:
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/IISError.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/IISError.png)

What do I do with it. Please help,thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows 404.3 i.e. MIME type restriction. You will need to configure PHP on IIS 7. This may help [Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/), [Set Up FastCGI for PHP](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/375/set-up-fastcgi-for-php/) or alternately [How to Install the Microsoft Web Platform for PHP](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/773/how-to-install-the-microsoft-web-platform-for-php/)

Comment: exactly, a common problem on IIS, PHP needs to run an interpreter and by default IIS is not aware of this.

Comment: well, i would not call it a problem. You need to configure the isapi's handlers for IIS to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have mapped your WAMP server to port 80, you should try and change the IIS port to 81, 8080 or something else.